# Шаблон для кнопки в telegrambot

Tags: python, sql, telegram-bot, telegram

```
                if call.data == 'cherep':
                        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
                        item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('+', callback_data='cplus')
                        item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('-', callback_data='cminus')
                        backass = types.InlineKeyboardButton('назад', callback_data='assort')
                        markup.add(item6,item7,backass)
                        bot.edit_message_media(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, reply_markup=markup,message_id=call.message.id,media=types.InputMediaPhoto(open('pong.jpeg','rb')))
                        bot.edit_message_caption(chat_id=call.message.chat.id,caption='череп',message_id=call.message.id, reply_markup=markup)



                if call.data == 'cminus':
                        cursor.execute(f"SELECT cherep FROM users WHERE user={call.message.chat.id}")
                        if cursor.fetchone()[0] >= 1:
                                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
                                cursor.execute(f'UPDATE users SET cherep=cherep-1 WHERE user={call.message.chat.id}')
                                conn.commit()
                                item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('+', callback_data='cplus')
                                item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('-', callback_data='cminus')
                               # add = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Добавить',callback_data='addc')
                                backass = types.InlineKeyboardButton('назад', callback_data='assort')
                                markup.add(item6,item7,backass)
                                cursor.execute(f"SELECT cherep FROM users WHERE user={call.message.chat.id}")
                                bot.edit_message_caption(chat_id=call.message.chat.id,message_id=call.message.id,caption= 'череп - ' + str(cursor.fetchone()[0]),reply_markup=markup)


                if call.data == 'cplus':
                        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
                        cursor.execute(f'UPDATE users SET cherep=cherep+1 WHERE user={call.message.chat.id}')
                        conn.commit()
                        item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('+', callback_data='cplus')
                        item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('-', callback_data='cminus')
                        #add = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Добавить',callback_data='addc')
                        backass = types.InlineKeyboardButton('назад', callback_data='assort')
                        markup.add(item6,item7,backass)
                        cursor.execute(f"SELECT cherep FROM users WHERE user={call.message.chat.id}")
                        bot.edit_message_caption(chat_id=call.message.chat.id,message_id=call.message.id,caption= 'череп - ' + str(cursor.fetchone()[0]),reply_markup=markup)
```

У меня есть этот код,первая кнопка это кнопка cherep которая присылает текст с изображением cplus(cherepplus)и(cherepminus)это просто прибавление или уменьшение числа товара из таблицы sql так вот
Мне нужно очень много таких карточек с товарами и по сути это шаблон в котором я меняю название кнопки название самих кнопок и редактируемый текст
Можно ли это сделать как то шаблоном и каждый раз просто подставлять значения?